# ¿Como se compara un String array con un String?

Tags: java, array, string

```
for(int casillas = 0;casillas<=99;casillas++){
     if(negocio[casillas] == alquilerV){
    System.out.println("\nID de Propiedad: "+id_prop[casillas]+"\n"+"Tipo de propiedad: "+tipo[casillas]+"\n"+"Dirección de la propiedad: "+direccion[casillas]+"\n"+"Barrio de de la propiedad: "+barrio[casillas]+"\n"+"Propiedad de negocio o alquiler: "+negocio[casillas]+"\n"+"Precio de propiedad: "+precio[casillas]+"\n"+"Gastos comunes de propiedad: "+gastos_comunes[casillas]);
```

Lo que quiero hacer es que si se cumple que casilla tiene alquiler se ejecuté el código pero el "==" no funciona.
Como lo hago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ¿Como se compara un String array con un String?

La forma correcta de comparar dos cadenas en Java, es usando el método [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)).

Solo deberías cambiar esta línea:

```
if(negocio[casillas] == alquilerV)
```

Por esta:

```
if(negocio[casillas].equals(alquilerV))
```

El método [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) retorna 1 si las dos cadenas son iguales.

Ahora si quieres comparar dos cadenas sin importar que la una sea mayúscula y la otra minúscula, deberías usar [equalsIgnoreCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equalsIgnoreCase(java.lang.String)) (por ejemplo, si la primera cadena se llama Jose y la segunda JOSE, el resultado de esta comparación daría `true`).

La condición quedaría así:

```
if(negocio[casillas].equalsIgnoreCase(alquilerV))
```

**¿Por qué esta condición no da verdadero?**

```
if(negocio[casillas] == alquilerV)
```

Porqué estás comparando referencias. Es decir, la dirección de memoria que tenga `negocio[casillas]` será diferente a `alquilerV`.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        String a = new String("Jose");
        String b = new String("Jose");
        if(a == b)
            System.out.println("Iguales");
    }
}
```

El resultado en pantalla será nada. Esto se debe porqué se está comparando el contenido de los dos punteros implícitos `a`y `b`. Es decir, el puntero `a` hace referencia a un objeto y `b` a otro objeto.

**¿En que momento esa condición puede dar verdadero?**

Si declaras una variable de tipo `string` sin hacer uso de la palabra clave `new`, daría como resultado un `true`.

Por ejemplo:

```
class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        String a = "Jose";
        String b = "Jose";
        if(a == b)
            System.out.println("Iguales");
    }
}
```

El resultado por pantalla, será `Iguales`. Para entender el porqué, necesitamos saber que en java existe un concepto llamado [StringPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacardx/annotations/StringPool.html). Básicamente, el [StringPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacardx/annotations/StringPool.html) es un grupo donde se almacenan cadenas constantes y esto ayuda ahorrar memoria.

En el ejemplo de arriba, cuando esta sentencia se ejecute:

```
String a = "Jose";
```

El JVM verificará si la cadena `Jose` se encuentra en el [StringPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacardx/annotations/StringPool.html), si no lo está, lo agrega al grupo.

Ahora, cuando se ejecute esta instrucción:

```
String b = "Jose";
```

EL JVM volverá a verificar si la cadena `Jose` se encuentra en el [StringPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javacard/3.0.5/api/javacardx/annotations/StringPool.html), pero como si lo encontró, hace que el puntero `b` haga referencia al mismo objeto al que apuntaba `a` (date cuenta, que esto ahorra en crear un nuevo objeto). Entonces al momento de comparar:

```
if(a == b)
```

Dará `true`, porqué los punteros `a` y `b` apuntan al mismo objeto.

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme y explicarme porque no me funcinaba

Comment: De nada @CodeZeroTwo. No olvides de marcar la respuesta que te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Si alquilerV es una variable solo asegurate que sea string, si quieres que sea igual a alquilerV debes ponerlo entre comillas negocio[casillas] == "AlquilerV", y debe ser exactamente igual

Comment: No me funciona lo que me dijiste pero gracias por intentar ayudarme.

Comment: En Java no puedes comparar así. En C# te podría estar funcionando tu código, ya que la clase String de C# sobrecarga el operador de igualdad (`==`).