# Utilizar un and logico para la condicion de if con Strings

Tags: java

Hola quería saber si hay alguna forma de poner en una condición esto:

```
if((vector[i]="hola") && (op == 1)){
...
}
```

Se que esta mal, solo quiero sabe si hay una forma de ponerlo. Me da este error
:*The operator && is undefined for the argument type(s) String, boolean*

Tampoco puedo cambiar && por and, tambien me sale error. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola Leonardo, ¿qué es lo que quieres evaluar y de qué tipo es cada dato?

Comment: Tal vez esto te ayude: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305400/como-se-compara-un-string-array-con-un-string/305417#305417

Answer (score 1):

`introducir el código aquí`Fijate capas que te da el error porque tenes un solo = alado de vector[i]

```
if((vector[i] == "hola") && (op == 1)){
...
}
```

Quedaria algo asi...

Comment: Esa no es la manera de comparar strings en Java. Para mas info: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/305400/como-se-compara-un-string-array-con-un-string/305417#305417